# Create a regular expression in htaccess for seemingly complicated subdomain with folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have many URLs like this:

http://blog.domain.org/blog/bid/365332/a-page-here

The number folder after "bid" changes and is random for every URL and "a-page-here" is different for every URL.

I need the regex to direct this type of URL to the following:

http://www.domain.org/blogs/a-page-here

Any help is appreciated as I do not know where to begin with this regex expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the document root of your "blog.domain.org" domain, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/bid/[0-9]+/(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/blogs/$1 [L,R]
```

to redirect.

Comment: @josephthrive This handles *everything* after that bunch of numbers, *anything* can be after that it it'll get passed to the redirect.

Comment: Great! Would there be a way to handle the first domain beginning each word with a capitol letter such as "A-Page-Here" to all lowercase such as "a-page-here"?

Comment: @josephthrive if you want to force lowercase, you'll need to have access to your server's vhost config in order to declare a rewrite map

Comment: I have this access. Do you know how to achieve this?